# slideUp() and slideDown() don't work but slideToggle() does

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In this JS Fiddle,

http://jsfiddle.net/bGKLn/

I wanted to slide "content" up and down when "bottom" is hovered. I can't get it to work, please help me out.

I tried slideToggle() and it worked but..out of curiosity.. why doesn't this work?

```
HTML

<div id="content">Content</div>
<div id="bottom" onclick="togle()"></div>
```

CSS

```
#content {
width: 400px;
border-left: 10px solid #FA802F;
border-right: 10px solid #FA802F;
text-align: center;
padding: 100px 0px 100px 0px;
display: none;
}
#bottom {
width: 420px;
height: 100px;
background-color: #FA602F;
border-bottom-left-radius: 100px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 100px;
}
```

Java script

```
function togle() {
var x = document.getElementById("content");

if (x.style.display.value.match("none")) {
    $("#content").slideDown("slow");
} else {
    $("#content").slideUp("slow");
}
}
```

Comment: you have and error in your code, the property value doesn't exits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
x.style.display.value.match("none")
```

with something like

```
x.style.display != "block"
```

as `x.style.display` returns a string, which has no `value` property, and you'll get

```
function togle() {
    var x = document.getElementById("content");

    if (x.style.display != "block") {
        $("#content").slideDown("slow");
    } else {
        $("#content").slideUp("slow");
    }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/bGKLn/1/)

or a little more jQuery'ish

```
$('#content').is(':visible')
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/bGKLn/2/)

or a lot more jQuery'ish, just use `slideToggle()` ?

Comment: That was quick and thank you, that solved my question.

Comment: By the way what does .src return, I mean has it got a .value property?

Comment: No, none of the elements properties has a `value` property, but value is a property itself, as in `element.value`, but there is no `element.src.value`, it's just `element.src`